# Can't install Python 3.10.0 with pyenv on MacOS

Tags: python, macos, pyenv

Trying to install Python 3.10.0 on MacOS 11.6 (Intel) with pyenv 2.1.0 (from homebrew) fails with:

```
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.10.0.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.0/Python-3.10.0.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.10.0...
python-build: use tcl-tk from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk

BUILD FAILED (OS X 11.6 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/rk/_qysk9hs40qcq14h44l57wch0000gn/T/python-build.20211006114013.40649
Results logged to /var/folders/rk/_qysk9hs40qcq14h44l57wch0000gn/T/python-build.20211006114013.40649.log

Last 10 log lines:
checking MACHDEP... "darwin"
checking for gcc... clang
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in `/var/folders/rk/_qysk9hs40qcq14h44l57wch0000gn/T/python-build.20211006114013.40649/Python-3.10.0':
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

The config.log in the build folder contains:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by python configure 3.10, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --prefix=/Users/jonas.obrist/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0 --libdir=/Users/jonas.obrist/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib --with-openssl=/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1 --with-tcltk-libs=-L/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/lib -ltcl8.6 -ltk8.6 --with-tcltk-includes=-I/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/include

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = Jonas-MBP-2018.local
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 20.6.0
uname -s = Darwin
uname -v = Darwin Kernel Version 20.6.0: Mon Aug 30 06:12:21 PDT 2021; root:xnu-7195.141.6~3/RELEASE_X86_64

/usr/bin/uname -p = i386
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = Mach kernel version:
     Darwin Kernel Version 20.6.0: Mon Aug 30 06:12:21 PDT 2021; root:xnu-7195.141.6~3/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel configured for up to 12 processors.
6 processors are physically available.
12 processors are logically available.
Processor type: x86_64h (Intel x86-64h Haswell)
Processors active: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
Primary memory available: 32.00 gigabytes
Default processor set: 614 tasks, 3158 threads, 12 processors
Load average: 2.13, Mach factor: 9.85
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/HEAD-483d95d/libexec
PATH: /usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/HEAD-483d95d/plugins/python-build/bin
PATH: /Users/jonas.obrist/.poetry/bin
PATH: /Users/jonas.obrist/.rbenv/shims
PATH: /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin
PATH: /usr/local/opt/libxml2/bin
PATH: /Users/jonas.obrist/.poetry/bin/
PATH: /Users/jonas.obrist/.cargo/bin
PATH: /Users/jonas.obrist/.local/bin
PATH: /Users/jonas.obrist/.fastlane/bin
PATH: /Users/jonas.obrist/.gem/bin
PATH: /Users/jonas.obrist/.pyenv/shims
PATH: /Users/jonas.obrist/.pyenv/bin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /Library/Apple/usr/bin
PATH: /Users/jonas.obrist/go/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2878: checking build system type
configure:2892: result: x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0
configure:2912: checking host system type
configure:2925: result: x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0
configure:2955: checking for python3.10
configure:2971: found /Users/jonas.obrist/.pyenv/shims/python3.10
configure:2982: result: python3.10
configure:3076: checking for --enable-universalsdk
configure:3123: result: no
configure:3147: checking for --with-universal-archs
configure:3162: result: no
configure:3318: checking MACHDEP
configure:3369: result: "darwin"
configure:3653: checking for gcc
configure:3680: result: clang
configure:3909: checking for C compiler version
configure:3918: clang --version >&5
Homebrew clang version 12.0.1
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin
configure:3929: $? = 0
configure:3918: clang -v >&5
Homebrew clang version 12.0.1
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin
configure:3929: $? = 0
configure:3918: clang -V >&5
clang-12: error: argument to '-V' is missing (expected 1 value)
clang-12: error: no input files
configure:3929: $? = 1
configure:3918: clang -qversion >&5
clang-12: error: unknown argument '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
clang-12: error: no input files
configure:3929: $? = 1
configure:3949: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3971: clang -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include   -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/Users/jonas.obrist/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/Users/jonas.obrist/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib conftest.c  >&5
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/jonas.obrist/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib'
configure:3975: $? = 0
configure:4023: result: yes
configure:4026: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:4028: result: a.out
configure:4034: checking for suffix of executables
configure:4041: clang -o conftest -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include   -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/Users/jonas.obrist/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/Users/jonas.obrist/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib conftest.c  >&5
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/jonas.obrist/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib'
configure:4045: $? = 0
configure:4067: result: 
configure:4089: checking whether we are cross compiling
configure:4097: clang -o conftest -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include   -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/Users/jonas.obrist/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/Users/jonas.obrist/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib conftest.c  >&5
In file included from conftest.c:8:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:93:16: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
        unsigned char   *_base;
                        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:93:16: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
        unsigned char   *_base;
                        ^
                          _Nullable 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:93:16: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
        unsigned char   *_base;
                        ^
                          _Nonnull 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:138:32: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
        int     (* _Nullable _read) (void *, char *, int);
                                          ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:138:32: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
        int     (* _Nullable _read) (void *, char *, int);
                                          ^
                                           _Nullable
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:138:32: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
        int     (* _Nullable _read) (void *, char *, int);
                                          ^
                                           _Nonnull
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:138:40: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
        int     (* _Nullable _read) (void *, char *, int);
                                                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:138:40: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
        int     (* _Nullable _read) (void *, char *, int);
                                                  ^
                                                   _Nullable
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:138:40: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
        int     (* _Nullable _read) (void *, char *, int);
                                                  ^
                                                   _Nonnull
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:139:35: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
        fpos_t  (* _Nullable _seek) (void *, fpos_t, int);
                                          ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:139:35: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
        fpos_t  (* _Nullable _seek) (void *, fpos_t, int);
                                          ^
                                           _Nullable
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:139:35: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
        fpos_t  (* _Nullable _seek) (void *, fpos_t, int);
                                          ^
                                           _Nonnull
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:140:32: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
        int     (* _Nullable _write)(void *, const char *, int);
                                          ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:140:32: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
        int     (* _Nullable _write)(void *, const char *, int);
                                          ^
                                           _Nullable
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:140:32: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
        int     (* _Nullable _write)(void *, const char *, int);
                                          ^
                                           _Nonnull
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:140:46: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
        int     (* _Nullable _write)(void *, const char *, int);
                                                        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:140:46: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
        int     (* _Nullable _write)(void *, const char *, int);
                                                        ^
                                                         _Nullable
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:140:46: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
        int     (* _Nullable _write)(void *, const char *, int);
                                                        ^
                                                         _Nonnull
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:144:18: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
        struct __sFILEX *_extra; /* additions to FILE to not break ABI */
                        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:144:18: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
        struct __sFILEX *_extra; /* additions to FILE to not break ABI */
                        ^
                          _Nullable 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:144:18: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
        struct __sFILEX *_extra; /* additions to FILE to not break ABI */
                        ^
                          _Nonnull 
In file included from conftest.c:8:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:220:5: error: 'TARGET_OS_IPHONE' is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Werror,-Wundef-prefix=TARGET_OS_]
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:67:13: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
extern FILE *__stdinp;
            ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:67:13: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
extern FILE *__stdinp;
            ^
              _Nullable 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:67:13: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
extern FILE *__stdinp;
            ^
              _Nonnull 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:386:41: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
                 int (* _Nullable)(void *, const char *, int),
                                        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:386:41: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
                 int (* _Nullable)(void *, const char *, int),
                                        ^
                                         _Nullable
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:386:41: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
                 int (* _Nullable)(void *, const char *, int),
                                        ^
                                         _Nonnull
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:386:55: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
                 int (* _Nullable)(void *, const char *, int),
                                                      ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:386:55: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
                 int (* _Nullable)(void *, const char *, int),
                                                      ^
                                                       _Nullable
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:386:55: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
                 int (* _Nullable)(void *, const char *, int),
                                                      ^
                                                       _Nonnull
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:387:44: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
                 fpos_t (* _Nullable)(void *, fpos_t, int),
                                           ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:387:44: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
                 fpos_t (* _Nullable)(void *, fpos_t, int),
                                           ^
                                            _Nullable
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:387:44: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
                 fpos_t (* _Nullable)(void *, fpos_t, int),
                                           ^
                                            _Nonnull
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:388:41: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
                 int (* _Nullable)(void *));
                                        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:388:41: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
                 int (* _Nullable)(void *));
                                        ^
                                         _Nullable
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:388:41: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
                 int (* _Nullable)(void *));
                                        ^
                                         _Nonnull
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:384:6: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
FILE    *funopen(const void *,
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:384:6: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
FILE    *funopen(const void *,
        ^
          _Nullable 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:384:6: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
FILE    *funopen(const void *,
        ^
          _Nonnull 
13 warnings and 1 error generated.
configure:4101: $? = 1
configure:4108: ./conftest
./configure: line 4110: ./conftest: No such file or directory
configure:4112: $? = 127
configure:4119: error: in `/var/folders/rk/_qysk9hs40qcq14h44l57wch0000gn/T/python-build.20211006114013.40649/Python-3.10.0':
configure:4121: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0
ac_cv_env_CC_set=set
ac_cv_env_CC_value=clang
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value='-I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include  '
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value='-I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/Users/jonas.obrist/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include'
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value='-L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/Users/jonas.obrist/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib'
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_MACHDEP_set=
ac_cv_env_MACHDEP_value=
ac_cv_env_PROFILE_TASK_set=
ac_cv_env_PROFILE_TASK_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0
ac_cv_prog_PYTHON_FOR_REGEN=python3.10
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=clang

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ABIFLAGS=''
ALT_SOABI=''
AR=''
ARCH_RUN_32BIT=''
ARFLAGS=''
BASECFLAGS=''
BASECPPFLAGS=''
BINLIBDEST=''
BLDLIBRARY=''
BLDSHARED=''
BUILDEXEEXT=''
CC='clang'
CCSHARED=''
CFLAGS='-I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include  '
CFLAGSFORSHARED=''
CFLAGS_ALIASING=''
CFLAGS_NODIST=''
CONFIGURE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=''
CONFIG_ARGS=' '\''--prefix=/Users/jonas.obrist/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0'\'' '\''--libdir=/Users/jonas.obrist/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib'\'' '\''--with-openssl=/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1'\'' '\''--with-tcltk-libs=-L/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/lib -ltcl8.6 -ltk8.6'\'' '\''--with-tcltk-includes=-I/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/include'\'' '\''CC=clang'\'' '\''CFLAGS=-I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include  '\'' '\''LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/Users/jonas.obrist/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib'\'' '\''CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/Users/jonas.obrist/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include'\'''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS='-I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/Users/jonas.obrist/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include'
CXX=''
DEFS=''
DEF_MAKE_ALL_RULE=''
DEF_MAKE_RULE=''
DFLAGS=''
DLINCLDIR=''
DLLLIBRARY=''
DTRACE=''
DTRACE_HEADERS=''
DTRACE_OBJS=''
DYNLOADFILE=''
ECHO_C='\c'
ECHO_N=''
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
ENSUREPIP=''
EXEEXT=''
EXPORTSFROM=''
EXPORTSYMS=''
EXPORT_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='#'
EXT_SUFFIX=''
FRAMEWORKALTINSTALLFIRST=''
FRAMEWORKALTINSTALLLAST=''
FRAMEWORKINSTALLAPPSPREFIX=''
FRAMEWORKINSTALLFIRST=''
FRAMEWORKINSTALLLAST=''
FRAMEWORKPYTHONW=''
FRAMEWORKUNIXTOOLSPREFIX='/Users/jonas.obrist/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0'
GITBRANCH=''
GITTAG=''
GITVERSION=''
GNULD=''
GREP=''
HAS_GIT='no-repository'
HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME=''
HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R=''
HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R_3_ARG=''
HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R_5_ARG=''
HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R_6_ARG=''
INSTALL_DATA=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM=''
INSTALL_SCRIPT=''
INSTSONAME=''
LDCXXSHARED=''
LDFLAGS='-L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/Users/jonas.obrist/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib'
LDFLAGS_NODIST=''
LDLIBRARY=''
LDLIBRARYDIR=''
LDSHARED=''
LDVERSION=''
LIBC=''
LIBFFI_INCLUDEDIR=''
LIBM=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBPL=''
LIBPYTHON=''
LIBRARY=''
LIBRARY_DEPS=''
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL_CRUFT=''
LINKCC=''
LINKFORSHARED=''
LIPO_32BIT_FLAGS=''
LIPO_INTEL64_FLAGS=''
LLVM_AR=''
LLVM_AR_FOUND=''
LLVM_PROFDATA=''
LLVM_PROF_ERR=''
LLVM_PROF_FILE=''
LLVM_PROF_FOUND=''
LLVM_PROF_MERGER=''
LN=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MACHDEP='darwin'
MACHDEP_OBJS=''
MAINCC=''
MKDIR_P=''
MULTIARCH=''
MULTIARCH_CPPFLAGS=''
NO_AS_NEEDED=''
OBJEXT=''
OPENSSL_INCLUDES=''
OPENSSL_LDFLAGS=''
OPENSSL_LIBS=''
OPENSSL_RPATH=''
OPT=''
OTHER_LIBTOOL_OPT=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='https://bugs.python.org/'
PACKAGE_NAME='python'
PACKAGE_STRING='python 3.10'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='python'
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION='3.10'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PGO_PROF_GEN_FLAG=''
PGO_PROF_USE_FLAG=''
PKG_CONFIG=''
PLATFORM_TRIPLET=''
PLATLIBDIR=''
PROFILE_TASK=''
PY3LIBRARY=''
PYTHONFRAMEWORK=''
PYTHONFRAMEWORKDIR='no-framework'
PYTHONFRAMEWORKIDENTIFIER='org.python.python'
PYTHONFRAMEWORKINSTALLDIR=''
PYTHONFRAMEWORKPREFIX=''
PYTHON_FOR_BUILD='./$(BUILDPYTHON) -E'
PYTHON_FOR_REGEN='python3.10'
PY_ENABLE_SHARED=''
READELF=''
RUNSHARED=''
SED=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
SHLIBS=''
SHLIB_SUFFIX=''
SOABI=''
SOVERSION='1.0'
SRCDIRS=''
STATIC_LIBPYTHON=''
TCLTK_INCLUDES=''
TCLTK_LIBS=''
TEST_MODULES=''
THREADHEADERS=''
TRUE=''
TZPATH=''
UNIVERSALSDK=''
UNIVERSAL_ARCH_FLAGS=''
VERSION='3.10'
WHEEL_PKG_DIR=''
_PYTHON_HOST_PLATFORM=''
ac_ct_AR=''
ac_ct_CC='clang'
ac_ct_CXX=''
ac_ct_READELF=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='darwin20.6.0'
build_vendor='apple'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_os='darwin20.6.0'
host_vendor='apple'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libdir='/Users/jonas.obrist/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/Users/jonas.obrist/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
runstatedir='${localstatedir}/run'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define _GNU_SOURCE 1
#define _NETBSD_SOURCE 1
#define __BSD_VISIBLE 1
#define _DARWIN_C_SOURCE 1
#define _PYTHONFRAMEWORK ""

configure: exit 1
```

I am able to build it manually by downloading the tarball and `./configure && make`

How can I get it to install?

Comment: Maybe you can add `CFLAGS=-w` to the environment variables? (suppress all warnings, as the error seem to be caused by a warning treated as an error)

Comment: I think Python 3.10 only got released today (?) so I'd stick with 3.9 for now, which i believe is the stable release at least for like a month or so.

Comment: @rv.kvetch I would like to start testing my stuff with 3.10 though, for which I need to install it.

Comment: @M.Zhang there's also one error in the log: "error: 'TARGET_OS_IPHONE' is not defined, evaluates to 0"

Comment: Does it work if you build from the tarball? It might be useful to figure out if the bug is with pyenv or with python's build process.

Comment: FWIW, it works for me (non M1); so the problem might be with your environment. Check your environment flags for nonstandard things.

Comment: @xrisk interesting, I can build it manually with `./configure && make`. I'd still prefer if pyenv could manage python for me rather than building it manually.

Comment: I assume you've already done `brew update && brew upgrade pyenv` - right?

Comment: @ojii I sugggest you try the build with a clean environment. For example, I can see that pyenv is picking up on your built version of llvm. Otherwise, you should probably file this as a bug on the pyenv repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I had a second version of clang installed (via homebrew), which interfered with the build. After running `brew uninstall llvm` pyenv/python-build picked the clang from xcode and now pyenv works again.

Answer (score 3):

Well I had almost the same issue on MacOS Monterey (12.0.1), and what worked for me was:

1. Reinstalling CommandLineTools from scratch:

```sh
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
sudo xcode-select --install
```

2. Reinstalling some command line tools using Homebrew:

```sh
brew update && brew upgrade && brew reinstall zlib openssl bzip2 readline
```

3. Installing the required Python version (3.10.0 in this case) by using flags configuration as shown below:

```sh
CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include \
   -I$(brew --prefix bzip2)/include \
   -I$(brew --prefix readline)/include \
   -I$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/include" \
LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib \
   -L$(brew --prefix readline)/lib \
   -L$(brew --prefix zlib)/lib \
   -L$(brew --prefix bzip2)/lib" \
   pyenv install 3.10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, still no idea why, but I just tried and it's working for me (terminal output below). I'm running Mac OS Big Sur, version 11.5.2 with an Intel i7 processor. My pyenv version is also the latest (2.1.0)

```sh
$ pyenv install 3.10.0
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.10.0.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.0/Python-3.10.0.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.10.0...
python-build: use tcl-tk from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk
Installed Python-3.10.0 to /Users/myuser/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0
```

Before this I did:

```
brew update && brew upgrade pyenv
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
sudo xcode-select --install
```

It worked for me!

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66522514/6319240

Comment: I met the same problem, and this solution worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still facing this issue. This worked for me

```
cd ~/.pyenv/plugins/python-build && git pull
```

Please refer
https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue, which was resolved by setting the `$CC` environment variable to `clang`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Try `env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"`

(that works for me for other Python-related tools, I don't use pyenv myself).

Rationale: modern macOS supports 2 architectures: intel (x86_64) and m1 (arm-something). Compiling for only one architecture is easier.

Comment: I get the same error with that env var set.