# pyenv install of Python errors with missing separators

Tags: python, pyenv

I'm running macOS 11.6 on Intel and it's giving errors when I try to install multiple versions of Python. I did see [a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69459268/cant-install-python-3-10-0-with-pyenv-on-macos) but it doesn't appear I'm using a non-standard compiler as neither llvm or clang are installed with homebrew.

```
~ % clang --version
Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

```
~ % pyenv install 3.10.0
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Installing Python-3.10.0...
python-build: use tcl-tk from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk

BUILD FAILED (OS X 11.6 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/t5/gx_568vj4w958qgxx_hhklvc0000gn/T/python-build.20211008082840.53425
Results logged to /var/folders/t5/gx_568vj4w958qgxx_hhklvc0000gn/T/python-build.20211008082840.53425.log

Last 10 log lines:
config.status: creating pyconfig.h
creating Modules/Setup.local
creating Makefile


If you want a release build with all stable optimizations active (PGO, etc),
please run ./configure --enable-optimizations


Makefile:222: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same problem and filed https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/2102

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by running `rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar/tcl-tk/8.6.11_1.reinstall` and installing from `pyenv`. It appears there were duplicate tcl-tk installs.