# Cannot install python 3.10.0 on m1 Apple silicon - ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: python-3.x, arm, apple-m1

I am trying to get python 3.10.0 installed on my Apple M1 Silicon.

Installing via asdf venv manager.
3.7.9 and 3.9.4 work without any issues but installing 3.10.0 causes the following error:

```
Last 10 log lines:
  "_libintl_textdomain", referenced from:
      __locale_textdomain in libpython3.10.a(_localemodule.o)
      __locale_textdomain in libpython3.10.a(_localemodule.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: clangerror: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Programs/_testembed] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [python.exe] Error 1
```

cmake version 3.22.0

Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

What I tried:

export ARCHFLAGS="-arch arm64"

and all the suggestions from

[Can't install Python 3.10.0 with pyenv on MacOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69459268/cant-install-python-3-10-0-with-pyenv-on-macos)

Thank you so much in advance, it's driving me nuts :-)

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not. But python 3.10.2 works. So that's fine for me.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

1. First install gettext:

```
brew install gettext
```

2. Then export flags:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/lib"; export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/include"
```

3. Finaly install python:

```
pyenv install 3.10.0
```

It worked for me. I found it here https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1877#issuecomment-962514298

Comment: This worked for me! Just notice that if you're not on Apple M1 but the "regular" Intel ones - use `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/lib` instead.

Comment: `brew install gettext` is all I needed. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issues after migrating from x86 to ARM architecture using Migration Assistant. I managed to fix it by removing the `gettext`, `openssl`, `readline`, and `tcl-tk` packages from /usr/local/Cellar (the directory dedicated for x86 architecture executables).

I find that identifying and removing the packages which cause compatibility issues is the most optimal solution for such issues instead of potentially running into the same issues again.

Answer (score -2):

Combined Volodymyr answer with:

```
arch --arm64 pyenv install 3.7.13
```

and it worked

Comment: I get the same error doing this...

Answer (score -3):

This worked for me:

```
arch -x86_64 pyenv install 3.10.4
```