# pyenv: "python >virtual env name< not installed"

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, pyenv

I am having trouble with pyenv after updating my macOS to 11.5. This is what I tried:

```sh
$ pyenv install 3.8.11 --skip-existing
$ pyenv virtualenv 3.8.11 >virtual env name<
$ pyenv local >virtual env name<
```

All of this works fine. Running `pyenv local` results in printing my virtual env's name. But I can't install dependancies or do anything with pip:

```sh
$ pip freeze
python >virtual env name< not installed
```

I tried following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51727036/9826415), but I still have the same problem.

Note: This is also happening with virtual envs that were previously working pre-update.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the issue was with updating pyenv and not macOS. All I had to do was add the following lines to my `~./zshrc` (or `~/.zprofile`:

```sh
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
```